# I am unable to get voice notification of HERE MAPS on REAL TIME NAVIGATION in app developed in flutter

Tags: heremaps

Tried a lot with code I can navigate over the route but it is not giving me any kind of voice notification to take turns left or right.

```
   void startNavigation1(Route route) {
_prepareNavigation(route);

// Stop in case it was started before.
_locationSimulationProvider.stop();

// Access the device's GPS sensor and other data.
// The navigator is set as listener to receive location updates.
_herePositioningProvider!.startLocating(_visualNavigator, LocationAccuracy.navigation);

_startDynamicSearchForBetterRoutes(route);
setupListeners2();
```

}

void setupListeners2() {
print('inside setuplistener2--------');
_visualNavigator.routeProgressListener = HERE.RouteProgressListener((HERE.RouteProgress routeProgress) async
{
Map jsonData = {
"load": load_info!.id,
"truck": load_info!.truck_id,
"load_size": "TL",
"token": str_accesstoken!,
"type": "GPS",
//"state": '_currentAddress',
// "country": "US",
// "postal": "10001",
"location": {
"coordinates": {
"lon": _herePositioningProvider!
.getLastKnownLocation()!
.coordinates
.longitude,
"lat": _herePositioningProvider!
.getLastKnownLocation()!
.coordinates
.latitude
},
"type": "Point",
}
};

```
  if (socket == null && (load_info!.status == 'Intransit' ||
      load_info!.status != 'Journey End')) {
    if (socket == null) {
      print(' inside socket');
      Socket? _socket =
      await SocketIOConnection()
          .connectToServer(
          str_accesstoken!);
      setState(() {
        socket = _socket;
      });
      socket!.connect();
      socket!.onConnect((data) {
        print('connected......');
        Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 20), (timer) {
          socket!.emit("gps", jsonData);
        });
      });
    }

    // Timer mytimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes:0, seconds: 15), (timer) async {
    //code to run on every 2 minutes 5 seconds
    // await SocketIOConnection().sendLocation(jsonData);
    // });

    // Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 20), (timer) {
    //   print('connected inside');
    //   print(jsonData);

    // });

    // timer= new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 15), () async {
    //   debugPrint("Print after 15 seconds");
    // //  await SocketIOConnection().sendMessage(socket!, jsonData);
    //   await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10000));
    //   await SocketIOConnection().sendLocation(jsonData);
    // await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10000));
    //
    // });
    // Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    //   debugPrint(timer.tick.toString());
    // });
    //


  }

  // Handle results from onRouteProgressUpdated():
  List<HERE.SectionProgress> sectionProgressList = routeProgress.sectionProgress;
  // sectionProgressList is guaranteed to be non-empty.
  HERE.SectionProgress lastSectionProgress = sectionProgressList.elementAt(sectionProgressList.length - 1);
  print('Distance to destination in meters: ' + lastSectionProgress.remainingDistanceInMeters.toString());
  //print('Traffic delay ahead in seconds: ' + lastSectionProgress.trafficDelay.inSeconds.toString());

  // Contains the progress for the next maneuver ahead and the next-next maneuvers, if any.
  List<HERE.ManeuverProgress> nextManeuverList = routeProgress.maneuverProgress;

  if (nextManeuverList.isEmpty) {
    print('No next maneuver available.');
    return;
  }





  HERE.ManeuverProgress nextManeuverProgress = nextManeuverList.first;

  int nextManeuverIndex = nextManeuverProgress.maneuverIndex;
  HERE.Maneuver? nextManeuver = _visualNavigator.getManeuver(nextManeuverIndex);
  if (nextManeuver == null) {
    // Should never happen as we retrieved the next maneuver progress above.
    return;
  }

  HERE.ManeuverAction action = nextManeuver.action;
  String roadName = _getRoadName(nextManeuver);
  String logMessage = describeEnum(action) +
      ' on ' +
      roadName +
      ' in ' +
      nextManeuverProgress.remainingDistanceInMeters.toString() +
      ' meters.';

  if (_previousManeuverIndex != nextManeuverIndex) {
    _updateMessageState('New maneuver: $logMessage');
  } else {
    // A maneuver update contains a different distance to reach the next maneuver.
    _updateMessageState("Maneuver update: $logMessage");
  }
  _previousManeuverIndex = nextManeuverIndex;

  if (_lastMapMatchedLocation != null) {
    // Update the route based on the current location of the driver.
    // We periodically want to search for better traffic-optimized routes.
    _dynamicRoutingEngine.updateCurrentLocation(_lastMapMatchedLocation!, routeProgress.sectionIndex);
  }


  if (str_action != 'Truck Location' ||
      str_action != 'Truck Drop Location') {
    // button_text == 'Check In Truck Location';
    // setState(() {
    //   flag3 = 1;
    // });
  } else {
    if (double.parse(str_distance!) <= 2) {
      SetTracking? setTracking =
      // await GetTracking(str_accesstoken, str_user_id)
      await GetTracking(str_accesstoken,context)
          .GetTrackingDetails();
      setState(() {
        _setTracking = setTracking!;
        button_color = _setTracking!.button_color;
        button_text = _setTracking!.button_text;
      });
      if (button_text == 'Check In') {
        setState(() {
          flag5=1;
          flag3 = 1;
        });
      } else if (button_text == 'Check Out') {
        setState(() {
          flag5=1;
          flag3 = 1;
        });
      } else if (button_text == 'Hook Now') {
        setState(() {
          flag3 = 1;
        });
      } else if (button_text == 'Drop Now') {
        setState(() {
          flag3 = 1;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  // Contains the progress for the next maneuver ahead and the next-next maneuvers, if any.
  // Contains the progress for the next maneuver ahead and the next-next maneuvers, if any.
  setState(() {
    maneuver_action =
        _visualNavigator.getManeuver(nextManeuverIndex)!.action.toString();
    str_direction = logMessage;
  });
  if (_previousManeuverIndex != nextManeuverIndex) {
    print('New maneuver: $logMessage');
  } else {
    // A maneuver update contains a different distance to reach the next maneuver.
    print('Maneuver update: $logMessage');
  }

});
// Notifies on voice maneuver messages.
_visualNavigator.maneuverNotificationListener = HERE.ManeuverNotificationListener((String voiceText) async {
  // Handle results lambda_onManeuverNotification().
  // Flutter itself does not provide a text-to-speech engine. Use one of the available TTS plugins to speak
  // the voiceText message.
  print("Voice guidance text: $voiceText");
  // setState(() async {
  maneuver_icon = getManeuveraction(maneuver_action!);
  print('icon :' + maneuver_icon!);
  await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(1.0);

  await flutterTts.setVolume(1.0);

  await flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);
  await flutterTts.synthesizeToFile("Hello World", Platform.isAndroid ? "tts.wav" : "tts.caf");

  await flutterTts.setVoice({"name": "Karen", "locale": "en-AU"});
  await flutterTts.isLanguageAvailable("en-US");
  await flutterTts.speak(voiceText);

  // flutterTts.speak(voiceText);
  // flutterTts.setVolume(150);
  // });

});
// Notifies on the current map-matched location and other useful information while driving or walking.
// The map-matched location is used to update the map view.
_visualNavigator.navigableLocationListener =
    HERE.NavigableLocationListener((HERE.NavigableLocation currentNavigableLocation) {
      // Handle results from onNavigableLocationUpdated():
      HERE.MapMatchedLocation? mapMatchedLocation = currentNavigableLocation.mapMatchedLocation;
      if (mapMatchedLocation == null) {
        print("This new location could not be map-matched. Are you off-road?");
        return;
      }

      _lastMapMatchedLocation = mapMatchedLocation;

      var speed = currentNavigableLocation.originalLocation.speedInMetersPerSecond;
      var accuracy = currentNavigableLocation.originalLocation.speedAccuracyInMetersPerSecond;
      print("Driving speed (m/s): $speed plus/minus an accuracy of: $accuracy");
    });

// Notifies when the destination of the route is reached.
_visualNavigator.destinationReachedListener = HERE.DestinationReachedListener(() {


  // Handle results from onDestinationReached().
  _updateMessageState("Destination reached. Stopping turn-by-turn navigation.");
  // Handle r
  print('Destination reached. Stopping turn-by-turn navigation.');
  print('str_action on destination reached:'+str_action.toString());
  if (str_action == 'Truck Location')
    // &&
    // str_action != 'Truck Drop Location')
      {
    setState(() {
      flag2 = 1;
      flag1=0;
      flag5=1;
      // flag3=0;
      str_next_consignment='Reached Truck Location';
    });
    if(socket!=null){
      socket!.disconnect();
      socket!.ondisconnect();
      print('......disconnected');
    }
    _settingModalBottomSheet();
  }
  else  if (str_action == 'Pickup')
    // &&
    // str_action != 'Truck Drop Location')
      {
    setState(() {
      // flag2 = 1;
      // flag2 = 0;
      // flag1 = 0;
      flag5=1;
      button_text = 'Check In';
      flag3 = 1;

      str_next_consignment='Reached Pickup Location';
      //button_text = 'Check In';
      // endflag=1;

    });
    if(socket!=null){
      socket!.disconnect();
      socket!.ondisconnect();
      print('......disconnected');
    }
    _settingModalBottomSheet();
  }
  else  if (str_action == 'Dropoff')
    // &&
    // str_action != 'Truck Drop Location')
      {
    setState(() {
      // flag2 = 0;
      // flag1 = 0;
      flag5=1;
      button_text = 'Check In';
      flag3 = 1;
      //flag2 = 1;


      str_next_consignment='Reached Dropoff Location';
      // button_text = 'Check In';
      // endflag=1;

    });
    if(socket!=null){
      socket!.disconnect();
      socket!.ondisconnect();
      print('......disconnected');
    }
    _settingModalBottomSheet();
  }
  else if (str_action == 'Truck End Location')
    // &&
    // str_action != 'Truck Drop Location').
      {
    Map data =
    {
      'load': load_info!.id,
      'event': 'Dropped Truck',
      "truck":load_info!.truck_id

    };
    UpdateJourneyStatus(data);
    print('data:'+data.toString());
    setState(() {
      str_next_consignment='Reached Truck End Location';
      flag1=0;
      flag5=1;
      endflag=1;
    }

    );
    if(endflag==1)
    {
      _selectendtrip();
    }
  }
  // else {
  //   setState(() {
  //     button_text = 'Check In';
  //    // endflag=1;
  //     flag3 = 1;
  //   });
  //   // if(endflag==1)
  //   // {
  //   //   _selectendtrip();
  //   // }
  // }
  if (socket != null)
  {
    socket!.onDisconnect((data) => print('disconnected'));
  }
  stopNavigation();

});


// Notifies when a waypoint on the route is reached or missed

// _visualNavigator.milestoneStatusListener = MilestoneStatusListener((Milestone milestone, MilestoneStatus milestoneStatus) {
//   // Handle results from onMilestoneStatusUpdated().
//   if (milestone.waypointIndex != null && milestoneStatus == MilestoneStatus.reached) {
//     print("A user-defined waypoint was reached, index of waypoint: " + milestone.waypointIndex.toString());
//     print("Original coordinates: " + milestone.originalCoordinates.toString());
//   } else if (milestone.waypointIndex != null && milestoneStatus == MilestoneStatus.missed) {
//     print("A user-defined waypoint was missed, index of waypoint: " + milestone.waypointIndex.toString());
//     print("Original coordinates: " + milestone.originalCoordinates.toString());
//   } else if (milestone.waypointIndex == null && milestoneStatus == MilestoneStatus.reached) {
//     // For example, when transport mode changes due to a ferry a system-defined waypoint may have been added.
//     print("A system-defined waypoint was reached at: " + milestone.mapMatchedCoordinates.toString());
//   } else if (milestone.waypointIndex == null && milestoneStatus == MilestoneStatus.reached) {
//     // For example, when transport mode changes due to a ferry a system-defined waypoint may have been added.
//     print("A system-defined waypoint was missed at: " + milestone.mapMatchedCoordinates.toString());
//   }
// });

// Notifies on the current speed limit valid on the current road.
_visualNavigator.speedLimitListener = HERE.SpeedLimitListener((HERE.SpeedLimit speedLimit) {
  // Handle results from onSpeedLimitUpdated().
  double? currentSpeedLimit = _getCurrentSpeedLimit(speedLimit);

  if (currentSpeedLimit == null) {
    print("Warning: Speed limits unknown, data could not be retrieved.");
  } else if (currentSpeedLimit == 0) {
    print("No speed limits on this road! Drive as fast as you feel safe ...");
  } else {
    print("Current speed limit (m/s): $currentSpeedLimit");
  }
});

// Notifies when the current speed limit is exceeded.
_visualNavigator.speedWarningListener = HERE.SpeedWarningListener((HERE.SpeedWarningStatus speedWarningStatus) {
  // Handle results from onSpeedWarningStatusChanged().
  if (speedWarningStatus == HERE.SpeedWarningStatus.speedLimitExceeded) {
    // Driver is faster than current speed limit (plus an optional offset, see setupSpeedWarnings()).
    // Play a click sound to indicate this to the driver.
    // As Flutter itself does not provide support for sounds,
    // alternatively use a 3rd party plugin to play an alert sound of your choice.
    // Note that this may not include temporary special speed limits, see SpeedLimitListener.
    SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click);
    print("Speed limit exceeded.");
  }

  if (speedWarningStatus == HERE.SpeedWarningStatus.speedLimitRestored) {
    print("Driver is again slower than current speed limit (plus an optional offset.)");
  }
});

// Notifies on a possible deviation from the route.
// When deviation is too large, an app may decide to recalculate the route from current location to destination.
_visualNavigator.routeDeviationListener = HERE.RouteDeviationListener((HERE.RouteDeviation routeDeviation) {
  // Handle results from onRouteDeviation().
  HERE.Route? route = _visualNavigator.route;
  if (route == null) {
    // May happen in rare cases when route was set to null inbetween.
    return;
  }

  // Get current geographic coordinates.
  HERE.MapMatchedLocation? currentMapMatchedLocation = routeDeviation.currentLocation.mapMatchedLocation;
  GeoCoordinates currentGeoCoordinates = currentMapMatchedLocation == null
      ? routeDeviation.currentLocation.originalLocation.coordinates
      : currentMapMatchedLocation.coordinates;

  // Get last geographic coordinates on route.
  GeoCoordinates lastGeoCoordinatesOnRoute;
  if (routeDeviation.lastLocationOnRoute != null) {
    HERE.MapMatchedLocation? lastMapMatchedLocationOnRoute = routeDeviation.lastLocationOnRoute!.mapMatchedLocation;
    lastGeoCoordinatesOnRoute = lastMapMatchedLocationOnRoute == null
        ? routeDeviation.lastLocationOnRoute!.originalLocation.coordinates
        : lastMapMatchedLocationOnRoute.coordinates;
  } else {
    print("User was never following the route. So, we take the start of the route instead.");
    lastGeoCoordinatesOnRoute = route.sections.first.departurePlace.originalCoordinates!;
  }

  int distanceInMeters = currentGeoCoordinates.distanceTo(lastGeoCoordinatesOnRoute) as int;
  print("RouteDeviation in meters is " + distanceInMeters.toString());
});

// // Notifies on voice maneuver messages.
// _visualNavigator.maneuverNotificationListener = HERE.ManeuverNotificationListener((String voiceText) async {
//   // Handle results lambda_onManeuverNotification().
//   // Flutter itself does not provide a text-to-speech engine. Use one of the available TTS plugins to speak
//   // the voiceText message.
//   print("Voice guidance text: $voiceText");
//   // setState(() async {
//     maneuver_icon = getManeuveraction(maneuver_action!);
//     print('icon :' + maneuver_icon!);
//     await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(1.0);
//
//     await flutterTts.setVolume(1.0);
//
//     await flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);
//    await flutterTts.synthesizeToFile("Hello World", Platform.isAndroid ? "tts.wav" : "tts.caf");
//
//    await flutterTts.setVoice({"name": "Karen", "locale": "en-AU"});
//     await flutterTts.isLanguageAvailable("en-US");
//     await flutterTts.speak(voiceText);
//
//     // flutterTts.speak(voiceText);
//     // flutterTts.setVolume(150);
//   // });
//
// });

// Notifies on the attributes of the current road including usage and physical characteristics.
_visualNavigator.roadAttributesListener = HERE.RoadAttributesListener((HERE.RoadAttributes roadAttributes) {
  // Handle results from onRoadAttributesUpdated().
  // This is called whenever any road attribute has changed.
  // If all attributes are unchanged, no new event is fired.
  // Note that a road can have more than one attribute at the same time.
  print("Received road attributes update.");

  if (roadAttributes.isBridge) {
    // Identifies a structure that allows a road, railway, or walkway to pass over another road, railway,
    // waterway, or valley serving map display and route guidance functionalities.
    print("Road attributes: This is a bridge.");
  }
  if (roadAttributes.isControlledAccess) {
    // Controlled access roads are roads with limited entrances and exits that allow uninterrupted
    // high-speed traffic flow.
    print("Road attributes: This is a controlled access road.");
  }
  if (roadAttributes.isDirtRoad) {
    // Indicates whether the navigable segment is paved.
    print("Road attributes: This is a dirt road.");
  }
  if (roadAttributes.isDividedRoad) {
    // Indicates if there is a physical structure or painted road marking intended to legally prohibit
    // left turns in right-side driving countries, right turns in left-side driving countries,
    // and U-turns at divided intersections or in the middle of divided segments.
    print("Road attributes: This is a divided road.");
  }
  if (roadAttributes.isNoThrough) {
    // Identifies a no through road.
    print("Road attributes: This is a no through road.");
  }
  if (roadAttributes.isPrivate) {
    // Private identifies roads that are not maintained by an organization responsible for maintenance of
    // public roads.
    print("Road attributes: This is a private road.");
  }
  if (roadAttributes.isRamp) {
    // Range is a ramp: connects roads that do not intersect at grade.
    print('Road attributes: This is a ramp.');
  }
  if (roadAttributes.isRightDrivingSide) {
    // Indicates if vehicles have to drive on the right-hand side of the road or the left-hand side.
    // For example, in New York it is always true and in London always false as the United Kingdom is
    // a left-hand driving country.
    print("Road attributes: isRightDrivingSide = " + roadAttributes.isRightDrivingSide.toString());
  }
  if (roadAttributes.isRoundabout) {
    // Indicates the presence of a roundabout.
    print("Road attributes: This is a roundabout.");
  }
  if (roadAttributes.isTollway) {
    // Identifies a road for which a fee must be paid to use the road.
    print("Road attributes change: This is a road with toll costs.");
  }
  if (roadAttributes.isTunnel) {
    // Identifies an enclosed (on all sides) passageway through or under an obstruction.
    print("Road attributes: This is a tunnel.");
  }
});

// Notifies which lane(s) lead to the next (next) maneuvers.
_visualNavigator.maneuverViewLaneAssistanceListener =
    HERE.ManeuverViewLaneAssistanceListener((HERE.ManeuverViewLaneAssistance laneAssistance) {
      // Handle events from onLaneAssistanceUpdated().
      // This lane list is guaranteed to be non-empty.
      List<HERE.Lane> lanes = laneAssistance.lanesForNextManeuver;
      logLaneRecommendations(lanes);

      List<HERE.Lane> nextLanes = laneAssistance.lanesForNextNextManeuver;
      if (nextLanes.isNotEmpty) {
        print("Attention, the next next maneuver is very close.");
        print("Please take the following lane(s) after the next maneuver: ");
        logLaneRecommendations(nextLanes);
      }
    });

// Notifies which lane(s) allow to follow the route.
_visualNavigator.junctionViewLaneAssistanceListener =
    HERE.JunctionViewLaneAssistanceListener((HERE.JunctionViewLaneAssistance junctionViewLaneAssistance) {
      List<HERE.Lane> lanes = junctionViewLaneAssistance.lanesForNextJunction;
      if (lanes.isEmpty) {
        _updateMessageState("You have passed the complex junction.");
      } else {
        _updateMessageState("Attention, a complex junction is ahead.");
        logLaneRecommendations(lanes);
      }
    });

// Notifies truck drivers on road restrictions ahead.
// For example, there can be a bridge ahead not high enough to pass a big truck
// or there can be a road ahead where the weight of the truck is beyond it's permissible weight.
// This event notifies on truck restrictions in general,
// so it will also deliver events, when the transport type was set to a non-truck transport type.
// The given restrictions are based on the HERE database of the road network ahead.
_visualNavigator.truckRestrictionsWarningListener =
    HERE.TruckRestrictionsWarningListener((List<HERE.TruckRestrictionWarning> list) {
      // The list is guaranteed to be non-empty.
      for (HERE.TruckRestrictionWarning truckRestrictionWarning in list) {
        if (truckRestrictionWarning.distanceType == HERE.DistanceType.ahead) {
          print("TruckRestrictionWarning ahead in: ${truckRestrictionWarning.distanceInMeters} meters.");
        } else if (truckRestrictionWarning.distanceType == HERE.DistanceType.passed) {
          print("A restriction just passed.");
        }
        // One of the following restrictions applies ahead, if more restrictions apply at the same time,
        // they are part of another TruckRestrictionWarning element contained in the list.
        if (truckRestrictionWarning.weightRestriction != null) {
          // For now only one weight type (= truck) is exposed.
          HERE.WeightRestrictionType type = truckRestrictionWarning.weightRestriction!.type;
          int value = truckRestrictionWarning.weightRestriction!.valueInKilograms;
          print("TruckRestriction for weight (kg): ${type.toString()}: $value");
        }
        if (truckRestrictionWarning.dimensionRestriction != null) {
          // Can be either a length, width or height restriction of the truck. For example, a height
          // restriction can apply for a tunnel. Other possible restrictions are delivered in
          // separate TruckRestrictionWarning objects contained in the list, if any.
          HERE.DimensionRestrictionType type = truckRestrictionWarning.dimensionRestriction!.type;
          int value = truckRestrictionWarning.dimensionRestriction!.valueInCentimeters;
          print("TruckRestriction for dimension: ${type.toString()}: $value");
        }
      }
    });

// Notifies whenever any textual attribute of the current road changes, i.e., the current road texts differ
// from the previous one. This can be useful during tracking mode, when no maneuver information is provided.
_visualNavigator.roadTextsListener = HERE.RoadTextsListener((HERE.RoadTexts roadTexts) {
  // See _getRoadName() how to get the current road name from the provided RoadTexts.
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The HERE SDK itself does not provide any mechanism to play TTS voices. It only prompts the text message that can then be used to "speak" the text. If these prompts are received by your application, it's rather a question related to your TTS implementation.

If you use a Flutter TTS plugin, try to create an isolated example, to hear if it can speak any text at all.

There can be also issues with the device's setup. In case of doubt, execute this HERE SDK [example app](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/android/Navigation): If the device is setup correctly, you will hear the voice message.